# What are QHT, QWT and QFT?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, terminology-and-notation

I am new to quantum computing. I am not able to understand QHT, QWT and QFT. I tried searching for a suitable material but still could not find them. It would be great if someone can explain and also a suggest a book to read these topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some Googling:

- [QFT - Quantum Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform)
- [QHT - Quantum Haar Transform](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2380848_Quantum_Haar_Wavelet_Transforms_and_Their_Applications)
- [QWT - Quantum Wavelet Transform](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9809004)

To be honest, so far I encountered only QFT which plays very important role in algorithms based on phase and amplitued estimatios (e.g. HHL algorithm for solving linear equations or Shor's algorithm for integers factoring). It is necessary to become familiar with QFT if you want to study quantum algorithms further.

Other transforms usage seem to be in a signal processing.
Any addition on these transforms is welcomed.

Comment: Thank you @MartinVesely. Can you suggest some book for these topics?

Comment: @ManuChaudhary: A classic is Nielsen and Chuang: Quantum Computation and Quantum Information. However, it can be too technical for beginers. You metioned that your are new to QC, so I would suggest to start here: https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html. Note that QHT and QWT seems complex topics for beginners.

Comment: Thank you @MartinVesely